# Calendar tag and ajax/jquery

Tags: channel, ajax, jquery

Im using the calendar tag on a page and an iframe below it to display an event page.
The iframe displays the latest event.
When you click on a day in the calendar it calls that days event into the iframe.

Here is the code to call up the day event:

```
<a href="{day_path='events'}" target="cal_frame">{day_number}</a>
```

Here is the existing iframe:

```
<div class="colThree_event_container">
  <iframe name="cal_frame" scrolling="no" src="{site_url}events"></iframe>
</div>
```

I have been trying to do away with the iframe and have the same functionality using just a div and ajax/jquery with no luck.

Any pointers? :-)

Comment: Please post some of the options you have tried in making this work as you wish - detailed explanations and/or code samples, and why they didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, here's the code:

Javascript:

```
$(function(){ 

    $('.ajax_link').on('click', function(e){ // catch the click, and bind that click-event to the variable "e"
        e.preventDefault(); // stop the event from firing (so user doesn't get forwarded to the actual link)

        var elem = $(this),
            link = elem.attr('href'),
            target = elem.attr('rel');

        $.get(link, function(data){ // do a GET-request
            $(target).html(data); // put the results in the target-element
        });

    });

});
```

I've made a Gist (which also includes the HTML): https://gist.github.com/4188501

Does that help?

Edit: updated code.

Comment: Hi, Wouldn´t that still be targeting the iframe? target="cal_frame". It needs to target only the div: [div class="colThree_event_container"] [/div]

Comment: No it wouldn't. The first thing we're doing after click is saying `e` (the click-event) `.preventDefault()`, so we're telling jQuery to stop it's default action (sort of like `return false`.

Comment: Ok, but I want to remove the iframe all together. I managed to do something like this:
            function ReplaceContentInContainer(id,content) {
                var container = document.getElementById(id);
                container.innerHTML = content;
            }
And then: <a href="javascript:ReplaceContentInContainer('colThree_event_container','{day_path='events'}')"> but it is only showing the actual url in the div: http://mysite.com/events/2012/11/23

Comment: I'll make a gist in a bit showing how you could do this fully. Hang on!

Comment: Hey sorry, dropped the ball there. Here's the gist: https://gist.github.com/4188501

Comment: Hi Steven, This works perfectly! Thanks so much for you time and effort. Really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem at all :). Would you mind marking this answer as correct by clicking the big "check"-mark on the left-hand side? Thanks!